# Removing a sublist from a main list without knowing its position in the list

Tags: python, arrays, list

So say i have a 2D list of randomly generated sub lists containing random numbers like this

```
list = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

How would I remove the sublist "(2,3)" from the main list if I didn't know its position in the list?
I tried using .pop but couldn't make it work without knowing the position of the sublist within the list.

Comment: `lst.remove((2,3))` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `remove` function might be what you are looking for:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm

```
list = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
list.remove((2,3))
print(list) # prints [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)] in python 3
```

However I would recommend you rename your variable to something other than `list` because that is a python keyword.

Comment: don't call your variable `list`